# Data picker populating correctly for one field but not the other

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a test project I am using to develop my code before I implement it in my real project. In the test, I have two fields that when tapped should bring up a dataPicker populated with the array for that field. This works fine for the first field (enterSeason) but the second (enterSport) returns just the keyboard. I have walked through the debugger and the variable are correct and the working the same for both fields. What am I missing? Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var enterSeason: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var enterSport: UITextField!

var dataPickerView = UIPickerView()
var season = ["2013", "2014", "2015"] //multi-season
//var season = ["2015"] //single-season
var sport = ["Baeball", "Football", "Basketball", "Hockey"]
var activeDataArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    enterSeason.inputView = dataPickerView
    dataPickerView.delegate = self
    dataPickerView.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == enterSeason {
        activeDataArray = season
    } else
        if textField == enterSport {
            activeDataArray = sport
        }
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return activeDataArray.count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return activeDataArray[row] as! String
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if activeDataArray == season {
        enterSeason.text = season[row] as! String
    }
    else if activeDataArray == sport {
        enterSport.text = sport[row] as! String
    }

}

}
```

This is my first project and I am learning a lot from S.O. Thank you for all you patient responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include

```
enterSport.inputView = dataPickerView
```

to set the correct firstResponder.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling it would be something simple I overlooked.

Comment: these are the best problems;)

Comment: I have a corollary question. When I enter my data from the first field (enterSeason) and then tap on the second field (enterSport), the dataPicker still has the data from the previous field's array. I ran the debugger and it is setting the activeDataArray var to the new value but the array populated in the picker does not change. Do I need to clear the picker? How would I do that?

Comment: Try calling dataPicker.reloadAllComponents()

Comment: That works if I click on enterSeason first (array of 3) and then click on enterSport (array of 4). But if I click on enterSport first then enterSeason, or anytime I click on enterSeason after I have clicked on enterSport, I get a crash and the debugger says fatal error: Array index out of range.

Comment: I tried to add `activeDataArray = []` ahead of `dataPicke.reloadAllComponents ()` but now after the first field picker is used, the dataPicker is empty no matter what field is tapped.  In the debugger, the shows activeDataArray = (_SwiftDeferredNSArray) "4 values" however the picker is empty.

Comment: can you provide the project?

Comment: Here is the test project where I am working on this code. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oriquslxaylmy1s/Test%20UIPIckerView.zip?dl=0)

Comment: In `textFieldDidBeginEditing`. Move the line `dataPickerView.reloadAllComponents()` all the way to the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Set dataPickerView as enterSport's inputview

```
enterSport.inputView = dataPickerView;
```